# How do I select a specific option value from a drop down list to show a hidden div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectors

I have a drop down list that has 4 options, so what I want is when I click on the value "from" it shows a hidden div (used CSS to hide this div "display: none;"). anyone can help me with that? THANKS!

Html:

```
<select id="type">
<option value="">--select--</option>
<option value="category">Category</option>
<option value="brand_name">Brand</option>
<option value="campaign_name">Campaign</option>
<option value="from">Recap date</option>
</select>
</label>

<div id="showfrom">
<input type="text" class="filter" value="02-16-2012" id="from">
</div>
```

Js:

```
$("#type").change(function() {
var selected = $(this).find(':selected').val();
if (selected == from) {
$("#showfrom").show();
}
});
```

Comment: **Typo?** `selected == from` quote from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`from` should be a string literal. Also you need to hide if something else is selected so better if you can use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle)

```
$("#type").change(function () {
    $("#showfrom").toggle(this.value == 'from');
}).change();//to set the initial state
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SaHNw/)

Comment: Great! make sense and more simple! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have another question if you could help please. I have another function and I want to run it once I choose a date from the calendar (<input type="text" class="filter" value="02-16-2012" id="from">) ?